# Find repeated substrings of length 3 in a string

Tags: java, strings

The following method receives a string and finds all occurrences of repeated substrings with a length of three characters, including spaces. Is this a good approach?

```
public Map<String, Integer> findOccurences(String str) {
        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        int counter = 0;
        String sub; 
        int stringLen = str.length() - 2;
        for (int i = 0; i < stringLen ; i++) {
            sub = str.substring(i, i + 3);
            if (map.containsKey(sub)) { 
                counter = map.get(sub); 
                counter++;
                map.put(sub, counter);
                counter = 0;
            } else {
                map.put(sub, 1); 
            }
        }
        return map;
    }
```

**Input**

> ```
> This This
> ```

**Output**

> ```
>  Th 1    <<< includes space 
> s T 1
> his 2
> Thi 2
> is  1    <<< includes space
> ```

Answer (score 8):

It's quite fine. The logic is simple and clear.
There might be a more clever solution (I don't know),
but probably it will be less clear.

A few improvements would be good though:

- `counter` is set to 0 at two places, both unnecessary, as the value is overwritten later
- It's a good practice to declare variables in the smallest scope where they are used. For example `counter` and `sub` would be better to declare inside the loop.
- `stringLen` is not a great name, because it's not really the "length" of anything. Even `limit` would be better
- Instead of the magic number 3, and `str.length() - 2`, it would be better to make the target length a method parameter.
- Instead of calling `.containsKey` followed by `get` and `put`, I prefer to `get`, check `null` and then `put`, whenever possible. This is not always possible, for example when `null` is a meaningful entry, but that's not the case here.

Based on the above suggestions, the implementation could become a bit simpler:

```
public Map<String, Integer> findOccurences(String str, int length) {
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    int limit = str.length() - length + 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        String sub = str.substring(i, i + length);
        Integer counter = map.get(sub);
        if (counter == null) {
            counter = 0;
        }
        map.put(sub, ++counter);
    }
    return map;
}
```

And it would be good to add a unit test for it:

```
@Test
public void test_This_This_() {
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("his", 2);
    map.put("Thi", 2);
    map.put(" Th", 1);
    map.put("s T", 1);
    map.put("is ", 2);
    assertEquals(map, findOccurences("This This ", 3));
}
```